# Calculating Balance from Deposit and Withdraw

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table name "CashTrasaction" that I want to be like this :

[image]

I want to Balance column automatically calculate from Deposit and withdraw that deposit add value to balance and withdraw subtract from Balance.
help me how to calculate!

Comment: *storing* the balance value is usually a mistake - all it adds is the opportunity for it to be *incorrect*. If you want correct balances you can always *calculate* them during retrieval.

Comment: Add each transaction row by row in other table.

Comment: "help me how to calculate!" What, how to subtract? Or do you know how to do that and are asking how to make a calculated column? Didn't you find any documentation on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script gives you expected Result

```
;WITH cte(AcNO,Dates,CheaqueNo,CompanyId,Deposit,Withdraw,Balance)
AS
(
SELECT 2014002,2017-12-19,12500,1,1000.00,0.00,1000.00  Union all
SELECT 30520,2017-11-13,12500,7,0.00,500.00,500.00      Union all
SELECT 50021,2017-10-19,1210,45,2500.00,100.00,2900.00  Union all
SELECT 54201,2017-11-29,121100,22,6000.00,0.00,8900 
)
SELECT * ,(SUM(Deposit)OVER(PArtition by AcNO Order by AcNO)
           +SUM(Balance)OVER(PArtition by AcNO Order by AcNO)
           -SUM(Withdraw)OVER(PArtition by AcNO Order by AcNO)
           )  AS CurrentBalance
FROM cte
```

Result

```
AcNO    Dates   CheaqueNo   CompanyId   Deposit Withdraw    Balance CurrentBalance
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30520   1993    12500           7       0.00     500.00     500.00     0.00
50021   1988    1210            45      2500.00  100.00     2900.00    5300.00
54201   1977    121100          22      6000.00  0.00       8900.00    14900.00
2014002 1986    12500           1       1000.00  0.00       1000.00    2000.00
```